# how to define deep copy of subclass if super class has customized deep copy

Tags: python, inheritance, copy, subclass, deep-copy

My super class A has a method copy(), which is a customized deep copy function. The sub class B wants to inherit this deep-copy function while also deep-copying its own member and methods.

In the following explaining example, the copy function only copies the "A part" of B. My question is how can I modify the copy function in order to also deep-copy the member T and method addOn() and other potential class features?

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, T):
        super().__init__()
        self.T = T
    def addOn(self):
        print("additional feature")
    def copy(self):
        return super().copy()
```

Comment: How about overriding the copy function and access attributes of parent rather than parent accessing attributes of child.

Comment: @mad_ I want to deep-copy all of the members and functionalities of B no matter whether it is originated from A or B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already made a good start, you just need to extend the subclass's copy function:

```
class B(A):
    ...
    def copy(self):
        new_b = super().copy()  # new_b now has all the A stuff copied
        new_b.T = however_you_copy_a_T_instance(self.T)
        return new_b
```

Since `addOn` is just a method, there is no need to copy it - it's implicitly part of any B instance.

As an aside, if you implement your class's copying functions as `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()` then your class will work properly with the built in copy and deepcopy stuff provided by  https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html (See the end of that page for more info).

Comment: About the "however_you_copy_a_T_instance", do you mean using the stuff like __class__, __new__,  __dict__ and memo? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The parent class A is from outside library. I have no idea why they don't just overwrite __deepcopy__()

Comment: Isn't `new_b` actually of type `A` in this case so the `AddOn` is not present?